# Force client to enter site from specific entry point in ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wasn't really sure on how to form the search terms for this question but I didn't really find what I was looking for either way, so here goes:

How would I force a client to only enter certain parts of my website from certain entry points? For example I have an overview of what activities the company I work in currently got going but I only want users to be able to enter the page responsible for adding a new activity by pressing the "Add New Activity" button.

So that you can't enter that page just by typing in the URL for example. How would one achieve this in ASP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way we do it in the real world, authentication, authorization. Whenever a visitor views a page on your website. They are sending a HTTP request, along with that request you'll receive any cookies that have been set by your web application on their computer on any previous visits, this happens on each and every request.

Authenticated users can be identified using cookies, usually what happens is... upon sign on, the server will set a cookie containing their identity. So when the authorized user requests to view "foo.com/topsecret" and the server receives that request, the server decrypts the data stored on the cookies and checks to see if its been tampered with... if all is good... access granted... if not... then it's simply denied.

Comment: Oh I know that process. What I was requesting was how I restrict a user to only access a site from a specific point on the website (in this case by pressing a specific button on the site). But I guess that's not necessary if I just check the user when the page loads.

Comment: Oh you mean from the client side... there really isn't much that you can do to enforce client side activity... What I mean by that is, if I know the direction that your button is going to send me... I can mimic the network traffic pretty easily to fool the server into believing I've performed x,y,z

Comment: Yeah I realized that a few minutes after reading your reply :P

Answer (score 1):

In your case u can use the Session Variables and in login u can check all permission.

In your page you can add a check in **Page_Load** same this:

```
User myUser = (User)Session["User"];
string page = Path.GetFileName( Request.Url.AbsolutePath );
if(!myUser.pageSee.Contains(page)){
  Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
}
```

you create a **User** class with proprerty a **list of strings** for the pages that you can view,
you may also add permissions for a single div.

Comment: I gave you a +1 for providing some code but Aydin Adn's answer is technically the most applicable generally which is why he got the "Correct Answer". :)

Comment: @Vipar don't warry... :) Thanks you